# Best solution for styled text within a uitableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, styledtext

Fo styled text (bold, italic, diff fonts and sizes), what's the best solution for putting a chunk of text within a cell? The text can of various lengths, so the cell would have to change it's height accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The Three20 framework provides a means to do just that, so you may want to give it a look.  If you don't want to use the framework, you can at least see how he accomplished it.

Latest code: http://github.com/facebook/three20/

-Rob